# New Facebook SDK and OAuthException in Graphpath requests

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-android-sdk

I saw a  buch of answers regarding this problem with the older versions of the SDK, and I can't seem figure out why this is happening to me.

if I use this code, it works perfectly:

```
String QUERY = "select uid, name, pic_square, is_app_user from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me())";
protected void getFacbookFirends() {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("q", QUERY);
    final Request req = new Request(getSession(), "/fql", params, HttpMethod.GET, fbCallback);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Request.executeBatchAsync(req);
        }
    });
}
```

but this is very ugly, so I tried using this instead:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session == null) {
    session = new Session(getActivity());
}
if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
    Request req = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session, "/me/friends?fields=id,name,installed,picture",
            new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            Log.w("FriendsListFragment.Facebook.onComplete", response.toString());
                }
            });
    Request.executeBatchAsync(req);
}
```

to my understanding, this is the exact same request and should run just the same way, but instead of getting the response I wanted, I get this `Response` object:

```
{Response:  
responseCode: 400, 
graphObject: null, 
error: {FacebookServiceErrorException: 
    httpResponseCode: 400, 
    facebookErrorCode: 2500, 
    facebookErrorType: OAuthException, 
    message: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
    }, 
isFromCache:false
}
```

any thoughts about how I can make this work nicely?

***EDIT:***

I tried running this code and still got the same result:

```
Request req = new Request(session, "/me/friends?fields=id,name,installed,picture",null, HttpMethod.GET,
        new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        Log.w("FriendsListFragment.Facebook.onComplete", response.toString());
            }
        });
Request.executeBatchAsync(req);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Request req = new Request(session, "/me/friends?fields=id,name,installed,picture",null, HttpMethod.GET, .......

Don't put the entire path in the graph path parameter, everything after the `?` should be in the params parameter that you set to null.  Try this instead:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("fields", "id,name,installed,picture");
Request req = new Request(session, "me/friends", params, HttpMethod.GET, .......
```

That will do the trick.

Comment: I think developers of FacebookSDK should include some verification code (whether parameters are included into request url). I spent few hours before found this answer.

Comment: I do the same thing.But still got the same error response.Please help me with it.What all permission required for to get the same result.

Comment: ooohhh sh+t!!!! I know i shouldnt post a comment to say thanks, but I need to do it. THANK YOU !!!