# can't get facebook graph data in specified language

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am using latest Facebook SDK for Android (3.0.2) and I want to retrieve notifications in a specified language. When I use this URL : `me/notifications` every thing works fine and I can receive data, but when I set URL : `me/notifications?locale=fr_FR`, I just receive empty object.

In facebook graph explorer both URLs work, but in my application only the first one is working.

This is my code :

```android
            session = Session.getActiveSession();
            if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
                Request request = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session, URLnotifications,
                        new Request.Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted( Response response) {

                        GraphObject object = response.getGraphObject();

                    }

                });

                request.executeAsync();

            }
```

The problem is in this variable :

```android
String URLnotifications = "me/notifications?locale=fr_FR"; // not working
String URLnotifications = "me/notifications"; // working
```

Comment: this is how I solved this issue : [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13937831/2579656)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("locale", "fr");
request.setParameters(params);
```